# Store debug data in format having good viewer support

Tags: debugging, logging, dataformat

I'd like to include various debug outputs in my Python program. Summary information and some variables should be saved in a file for later examination. This will be at different levels down to very verbose outputs in loops (that's why simple logging isn't enough). And maybe larger data dumps of large tables.
For debugging a bug, I'd like to examine the different data states of the program after the program has run. I want to filter entries (e.g. my module) and chose the desired verbosity level per module.

Do you know a good data format for that (i.e. storing different verbosity levels and being able to select one; dumping data tables)? Maybe one supporting a tree view and having a ready-made nice viewer. The tree view could relate to module and method names, but other ideas are welcome.

Comment: Meanwhile I've found http://www.hdfgroup.org/why_hdf/ to consider. Hopefully there will be more input, too :)